# In forge tests, how can I import events?

Tags: solidity, forge

In forge tests I've been redeclaring events within the test file so that I can use `vm.assertEmit`. Is there a way to import events from the contract I am testing instead?

e.g.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {RegistryDeployer} from "../src/RegistryDeployer.sol";

contract RegistryDeployerTest is Test {

  // re-declare event for assertions
  event Deployed();
  // ^^^^^^^^^^
  // I don't want to have to do this
  // ^^^^^^^^^^

  function testDeployer() public {
    vm.expectEmit(true, true, true, true);
    emit Deployed();
    new RegistryDeployer();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ditto for errors

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface where the event is defined, and import it both in your source contract and your tests contract:

```
interface MyEvents {
  event Deployed();
}

contract RegistryDeployer is MyEvents {
  // ...
}
```

In your tests you wouldn't need to re-declare it:

```
contract RegistryDeployerTest is Test, MyEvents {

  function testDeployer() public {
    vm.expectEmit(true, true, true, true);
    emit Deployed();
    new RegistryDeployer();
  }
}
```

I think your example is cleaner. AFAIK there is no direct access to the event with `RegistryDeployer.Deployer`, so I would do what you showed in your example.

Comment: I like this but for something like IERC1155 it means declaring each of the functions in the test class too which isn't really any better.